# Delete ListView Item row

Tags: android, listview

I have written code to **delete Image from SD Card**, and my code just works fine, ***what if i want to delete whole row, not just image***.

actually each and every row of List View contains, a image with two buttons, so whenever i do tap on remove button, it is just removing image not deleting that particular row.

```
final ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fileName = ImageList.get(position).toString().substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());
                 String fileToDelete = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + fileName;
                 Log.d("FileToDelete", fileToDelete);
                  File myFile = new File(fileToDelete);
                      if(myFile.exists())
                        myFile.delete();
                 ((BaseAdapter) lstView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
        });
```

**getView(...)**

```
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         // If this item is to be synced
            if(flags.get(position)) {
                startUpload(position);

            // Mark as synced
            flags.put(position, false);

        }
```

Comment: can you please put up your adapter class???

Comment: What is the data displayed by adapter? What collection of data?

Comment: You have to remove item from list  and call adapter with updated list.Suppose you have ArrayList myList then remove that item from myList and call your adapter with new myList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get view that you are binding to that listview. you can get that view using position variable. and delete like

```
myList.remove(position);
```

and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i used ImageList.remove(position);  berfore calling ((BaseAdapter) lstView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();  and done :)  i ticked as useful and will accept after 7 mins